# Building table with specifik data

Tags: matlab

I need some help with a task that I have:

I have 4 vectors with data: 3 of them are with dates and the 4th one is with overdue days, something like this:

```
dateAdded      dueDate    date       overdue
                         Published   
02/11/18       02/11/18   03/11/18    1
03/11/18       04/11/18   11/11/18    7
03/11/18       04/11/18   04/12/18    30
04/11/18       05/11/18   ongoing     overdue up to today
```

Can you give me some tips how can I create a table with the overdue days for each month from the year, considering that when I have transition from one month to another one I have to count the overdue to both months? Also when the datePublished hasn't come yet I have to count the overdue dates for each month passed.

Thanks

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using? Are your dates stored as chars/strings or as [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) objects? In case of the latter, this is quite trivial (simple subtraction).

Comment: I am using MATLAB  R2013a.
They are stored as number format and I am finding the months and days with the functions month(date) and day(date).
I know it is trivial but how would you construct it?

Comment: If the overdue is in units of days, can you not represent your days as some serial number (i.e. [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)) and subtract them? BTW, do you have to do this in MATLAB? I think something like Excel would be better suited for this task. Also, your MATLAB version is quite outdated. There were functions introduced in newer releases that simplify tasks such as yours. If you have no access to a newer MATLAB, you can use Octave.

Comment: @Dev-iL, thank you but I have found a solution for the task. With one for loop and a couple of if-else if statements inside of it. Also, the index position of elements for the different months is really important in order to have a proper output table with the desired data.

Comment: You might want to post your own solution as an answer, to help future readers having a similar problem.

Comment: @Dev-iL You are right, it should be something liek that:

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
  number_months = max(((year(dateAdded)-2018))*12 + rem(month(dateAdded),13));

idx = 1;
ii=1;

for k=1:number_months
      kpit(k,1) = k;
      kpit(k,2) = 0;
      kpit(k,3) = 0;
end



for i=1:data_length_Added
      %         if month(dateAdded(i)) == month(dueDate(i)) && month(dateAdded(i)) ~= 0
      if month(dueDate(i)) == month(datePublished(i)) && month(dateAdded(i)) ~= 0
            [~,idx]=ismember(month(dueDate(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');% finds the position of an element from the array in the array for months

            kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
            kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;
            idx = idx + 1;
      else if month(datePublished(i)) == month(dueDate(i)) + 1
                  [~,idx]=ismember(month(dueDate(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                  [~,idx1]=ismember(month(datePublished(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                  year1 = year(datePublished(i));
                  weight = (day(datePublished(i)))/eomday(year1,month(datePublished(i)));
                  kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
                  kpit(idx1,2) =kpit(idx1,2) + overdue(i)*weight;
                  kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
                  kpit(idx1,3) = kpit(idx1,3)+ 1;
                  if (month(datePublished(i)) ~= 0 && month(datePublished(i)) > month(dueDate(i))+1)
                        %                                if (datePublished > dueDate)% If the correction is done check every month if it is the next one
                        [~,idx]=ismember(month(datePublished(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                        year1 = year(datePublished(i));
                        weight = day(datePublished(i))/eomday(year1,month(datePublished(i))); %Should count all overdue days for full months and weighted overdue dats for not full months
                        kpit(idx,2) = overdue(i)*weight;
                        kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;
                        for j=(month(datePublished(i))-1):month(dueDate(i))
                              [~,idx]=ismember(month(datePublished(j)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                              kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(j);
                              kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
                              j = j +1;
                        end
                  end
            end
      end
      else if month(dueDate(i)) == 0
                  [~,idx]=ismember(month(today),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                  year1 = year(today);
                  weight = day(today)/eomday(year1,month(today)); %Should count all overdue days for full months and weighted overdue dats for not full months
                  kpit(idx,2) = overdue(i)*weight;
                  kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;
                  for j=(month(today)-1):month(dueDate(i))
                        [~,idx]=ismember(month(today),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                        kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(j);
                        kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
                        j = j +1;
                  end
            end
end
```

Comment: You might find these articles interesting: [1](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time), [2](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks :)